# Calling function from other function : how to pass the variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a first function :

```
$(document).on('change','#product select', product_selection);  
function product_selection() {
        var tableRow = $(this).closest('div.tableRow');
        var reference = //some function to retrieve the reference depending on product selected
        $(tableRow).find('.reference input').val(reference);        
    }
```

Then another function that retrieves the price depending on the quantity ordered :

```
$(document).on('change','#quantity input', price);
    function price() {
        var tableRow = $(this).closest('div.tableRow');
        var product = $(tableRow).find('#product select').val()
        var quantity = $(this).val();
        var price =  //some function to retrieve the price depending on product and quantity 
        $(tableRow).find('.price input').val(price);        
    }
```

Both these functions work fine independently. But i actually need to "link" them : when selecting a product, I want a default quantity (depending on the product) to be inserted and the price calculated immediately.

So what i did is I inserted the following line at the end of the first function :

```
$(tableRow).find('.quantity input').val(quantity).change();
```

It does the job but it's apparently bad in terms of performance.
I know i need to call the price function at the end of the product_selection function, but despite many tries i can't find the correct syntax. I know the problem comes from the "tableRow" variable that isn't passed to the 2nd function when calling it from the first.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, and certainly nothing to do with performance. Why do you believe this to be the case?

Comment: Because i tested and it takes almost a second to execute the whole thing when changing the product. It takes 10 milliseconds to execute when only changing the quantity. 
But you are probably right, maybe when doing $(tableRow).find('.quantity input').val(quantity).change(); it triggers other functions which cause the lag. I will investigate further then.

Answer (score 0):

If the elements are NOT dynamic, then no need to delegate from document - instead get as close as you can:

IDs MUST be unique so perhaps post your HTML?

```
   $("#product select").on('change', product_selection);  
   $("#quantity input").on('change', price);
```

You can also use a scope. I am not sure it is faster than find, but I use it often

```
var tableRow = $(this).closest('div.tableRow');
var reference = //some function to retrieve the reference depending on product selected
$('.reference input',tableRow).val(reference);        

var product = $('select',tableRow).val()
var quantity = $('.quantity',tableRow).val();
var price =  //some function to retrieve the price depending on product and quantity 
$('.price input',tableRow).val(price);
```

Comment: Thank you! The first solution works, I don't know why I didn't think about it... 
Also, thank you for the 2nd suggestion, part of the reason why i posted this is because i wanted to learn new things.